Cómo puedo asignar los datos de una api a una tabla con signals en Angular 17
Estoy creando una tabla reutilizable en Angular 17 con Angular Material y Signals. Tengo un componente llamado 'tablacompleta' el cual es la tabla reutilizable que es importado desde cualquier otro componente, en este caso lo importo en el componente 'dashboardmensajes'. Lo que trato de hacer es usar 'tablacompleta' como una plantilla para 'dashboardmensajes' y para ello uso signals en tablacompleta.ts:
 columns = input.required<string[]>(); // Éstas serían las columnas que rellenamos con los datos de la api
 displayedColumns = input.required<string[]>(); // Éstas serían todas las columnas incluyendo los checkbox entre otros.
 data = input.required<T[]>(); 

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<T>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.data = this.data(); 
  }

Luego en 'dashboardmensajes' trato de traerme los datos de un api para luego insertarlos en la tabla. En dashboardmensajes.html es donde llamo a la plantilla y le indico los datos que se requieren:
<main>
    <section>
        <h1>Mensajes</h1>

        <app-tablacompleta [columns]="columns" [displayedColumns]="displayedColumns" [data]="data"></app-tablacompleta>
    </section>
</main>

Y luego en dashboardmensajes.ts me traigo los datos de la api y los guardo en data, además de indicar las columnas a mostrar:
columns = ['id', 'nombre', 'apellidos', 'email', 'asunto', 'mensaje', 'fecha']; // Columnas que rellenamos los datos con la api
displayedColumns = ['select',...this.columns]; // Columnas que vamos a mostrar, que incluyen los checkbox
data: any[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.title.setTitle('Mensajes < EasyShop');
    this.getMessages();
  }

getMessages() {
    this.mensajeService.getAllMensajes().subscribe({
      next: (respuesta: Mensajescontacto[]) => {
        this.data = respuesta;
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    })
  }

La cosa es que no me muestra los datos en la tabla, pero si hago console.log(this.data) salen los datos correctos en consola. Luego he probado con el array ELEMENT_DATA que viene en la documentación de Angular Material (https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples): si lo pongo dentro de la función getMessages() con this.data = this.ELEMENT_DATA;, los datos no se muestran en la tabla. En cambio si lo pongo en el ngOnInit, fuera de getMessages(), se muestran en la tabla correctamente. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme por favor? Gracias.

Uh, me parece un poco confuso, para que usas la señal? Yo pensaría más en crear el componente de la tabla y dependiendo de donde la use enviar los datos, generado las columnas de la tabla con un ngFor o en el caso de necesitar algún tipo de campo especial puedes meter un switch para que te aparezca dependiendo. Así le hice en un proyecto reciente con multiples tablas CRUD, componente padre envía un tipo de dato donde vienen tanto los headers, como columnas y datos necesarios para generar la tabla, incluso mando las funciones para cada botón.

Te refieres a usar @Input de la forma tradicional no?
